# Using question mark if condition in print statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to print a sentence like:

```
   boolean someSetting = true; 
   System.out.println("Running experiment " + (someSetting)? "on" : "off");
```

Obviously this won't compile. Is there any other suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add brackets around it to evaluate that expression to `String` value

```
System.out.println("Running experiment " + ((someSetting)? "on" : "off"));
```

without brackets it tries to contact (`+`) `String` and `boolean` and puts it as a conditional expression which is invalid

Comment: Hey Thanks! I actually haven't been able to accept any answers because I didn't know how. Now I'll go back to my previous questions to accept answers... :)

Comment: nice you should do that :)

Answer (score 3):

That's easy enough to fix:

```
boolean someSetting = true; 
System.out.println("Running experiment " + ((someSetting)? "on" : "off"));
```